# C : receive the key , entity and response in a txt file

Tags: c, arrays, csv, key-value

I have a text file that contain the section heading , key and value. That look like this.

```
[what]
apple = apple is a fruits.
tv = television
[who]
steve = chemistry teacher
```

below is my codes

```
#define A1 1
#define A2 2
#define B1 3

/* to be implemented */
char intent[255];
char key1[255];
char key[255];
char inv[3][10] = { "what","where","who" };
char file[255];

FILE* fileGet;

typedef struct { char* key; int val; } fileGetStruct;

static fileGetStruct fileGettable[] = {
    { "apple", A1 }, { "tv", A2 }, { "steve", B1 } };

snprintf(intent, 255, "[%s]", inv[0]);
//printf("%s\n", intent);

//scanf("%s", key1);

if ((fileGet = fopen("txt.ini", "r")) == NULL) {
    printf("File not found");
    exit(1);
}
scanf("%s", key1);
while (fgets(file, 255, fileGet) != NULL) {
    if (intent == "[") {
        switch (inv[0][10]) {
        case A1:
            printf("apple is a fruits");
            break;
        }
    }
}
fclose(fileGet);
}
```

I am trying not to hard code this using c language. Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Solve it in what way?  Parse it?

Comment: That looks like a typical [INI file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file). Those are relatively easy to parse, but there are also many libraries that can help you with that.

Comment: I have tried lots of ways such as strcmp , switch cases and others but it is all hard coded which is wrong

Comment: @kelly Post your solution so we can see.

Comment: I have updated my codes above.

Comment: You can't compare strings like `intent == "["`. And `inv[0][10]` is out of bounds of `inv[0]`. And `inv[0][i]` for any valid index `i` is a single character that is not equal to the integers `1`, `2` or `3`. All in all it seems you could need to take a few steps back, and get some beginners books or take a few beginners classes about C.

Comment: `case` compares labels for equality, which is probably not what you want. One could use `strncmp`, but one probably wants a lexer, https://re2c.org/manual/manual.html#a-basic-example.

Comment: strncmp is part of hard code too... thats why i didnt want to use it.